# Using eval as prototype method name in JavaScript or NodeJS

Tags: javascript, eval, reserved-words

I know there are several questions on valid identifier names, property names, reserved words etc., but there is some variation (and much verbosity) in the answers. I would just like to know the answer for a very specific case.

The reason for wanting to use the name `eval`, is that this is for a node module that will actually evaluate code (in another language), so it feels like the most appropriate name.

So my question is:

Can I do this?

```
function Foo() { ... }

Foo.prototype.eval = function(args) { ... }
```

Or in ES6, this?

```
class Foo {
  ...

  eval(args) { ... }
}
```

And what would be the drawbacks, assuming this is technically valid?

Comment: The `eval` function is just `window.eval`. It’s just a property. There’s no conflict.

Comment: `eval` isn't a keyword; you can call your own methods whatever you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eval` isn’t a [reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords). It’s just a property on `window` or whatever `globalThis` is (e.g. `global` on Node). There’s no reason why there can’t be a property with the same name on a *different* object (`Foo`’s prototype).

All of these are valid, and all of these create a property with the key `eval` on *some* object:

```
function Foo(){}

Foo.prototype.eval = function(){};
new Foo().eval();
```

```
class Foo{
  eval(){}
}

new Foo().eval();
```

```
({
  eval: function(){}
}).eval();
```

To go even further, even if `eval` *was* a reserved word, all of these would still be valid. This is valid, because methods can actually have *any* name:

```
class Foo{
  if(){}
}

new Foo().if();

({
  if(){},
  var(){},
  for(){},
  switch(){}
}).var();
```

You just can’t use them on their own, like `const if = new Foo().if;` or `const {if} = new Foo();`, if they’re reserved words. `eval` would be fine here; it would just overwrite `window.eval`.

Comment: I also found [this list](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp) of reserved words, which confused things a bit. But I guess that list has more of a browser/window object context..?

Comment: @Gutte Ah yes, good old W3Schools! I wouldn’t trust that site…

Answer (score 0):

This is valid, `eval` is a property of the global object (`window` in browsers or `global` in node.js)

As a drawback, the main one I can see would be the *astonishment of a developer* seeing some `eval`, getting a bit scared / mixing it up with the global known `eval`.

Apart from that,  you can do it.

Comment: The ECMAScript [Realm proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-realms) has a method called `evaluate`. Maybe it should be called that as well. Or, if it actually evaluates another Language, why not call it `evaluateBefunge`, or whichever language is being evaluated? Just a few ideas.

Comment: Pac0 and @Xufox thanks for the answers and comments. I think I will go with evaluate and eval as an alias. One annoyance which remains is that my editor keeps highlighting the word eval...

Comment: @Gutte Oh yes… the Firefox console actually highlights it correctly; it recognizes `eval` as a property name in this context.